# What happened to the opera-next package?

Tags: opera, official-repositories

A week ago I noticed `opera-next` package in *New in repository* Synaptics' filter. So I installed it to test some HTML. Today I noticed that it has replaced `x-www-browser` alternative and tried to reproduce it but it was no longer in the repository. I don't remember enabling/disabling PPAs so it could be from official `partner` repository. And now it's gone. Was there some announcement about why was it removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opera-next was never an Ubuntu package. You got it from http://deb.opera.com

(FWIW, the `partner` repository isn't part of Ubuntu, either, it's an add-on repository from Canonical, that doesn't obey Ubuntu's rules)

Comment: But the word `opera` is not present in any file under `/etc/apt/` and I don't remember adding it. Are there any partner repository logs? I can't find them.

Comment: `dpkg` and `apt` have logs, but don't include the URLs of the repositories